# Gtk Group Check Button

Tags: python, button, gtk, group

I discovered Gtk grouped CheckButtons in the documentation at:

https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/tutorials/beginners/components/radio_button.html

But when I run the Python code, shown in the above:

```
# https://developer.gnome.org/documentation/tutorials/beginners/components/radio_button.html
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GdkPixbuf# GLib
live = Gtk.CheckButton(label="Live")
laugh = Gtk.CheckButton(label="Laugh", group=live)
love = Gtk.CheckButton(label="Love", group=live)

def on_toggled(button, identifier):
    is_active = button.props.active
    if identifier == "live":
        # update_live() is defined elsewhere
        update_live(is_active)
    elif identifier == "laugh":
        # update_laugh() is defined elsewhere
        update_laugh(is_active)
    elif identifier == "love":
        # update_love() is defined elsewhere
        update_love(is_active)

# The live, laugh, and love variables are defined like the example above
live.connect("toggled", on_toggled, "live")
laugh.connect("toggled", on_toggled, "laugh")
love.connect("toggled", on_toggled, "love")
```

I get a

`` TypeError: gobject `GtkCheckButton' doesn't support property `group' ``

error.

My Python version is Python 3.8.10. Can someone tell me what the problem is?

TKinter has:`tk.Checkbutton(..., indicatoron=0)`, but I presume Gtk does not have this kind of option for it's Radio buttons.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The tutorial you're reading is based on the most recent GTK version, which is GTK4, while you're developing using GTK3. The "group" property on GtkCheckButton didn't exist in GTK3 yet

Comment: You mean, Gtk3 isn't 'future' compatible? :-) I guess I will have to look forward to that feature. Thanks niesdg